# nginx ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

есть сайт на ubuntu16.04 там же стоит nginx + php-fpm
нужен доступ к сайту из локальной сети (без изменения в файле hosts).
на стартовую страницу nginx я попадаю по ip, а вот как попасть на сам сайт не могу догнать
конф:

```
server {
listen 192.168.28.146:80;
server_name consultation.net www.consultation.net;


root /var/www/consultation.net/web;


index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


location / {

try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}


location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;


fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
}
```

Comment: Если нужно попасть на сайт по IP из локалки то просто удалите default и рестартните nginx, вот если по url то тут вам поможет только внутренний dns.

Answer (score 0):

**на сервере**

Добавить сайт, используя мягкую ссылку в раздел активных:

```
# ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-availabe/sitename.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
# systemctl restart nginx
```

Если это единственный сайт, можете удалить сайт *default* из `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`

**на клиенте**

Если *GNU/Linux* добавте :

```
# echo "192.168.28.146    consultation.net" >> /etc/hosts
```

Если *Windows*, обновите файл *hosts*, в этой ОС это делается похитрее, поищите видео.

Если у вас свой внутрений DNS добавте запись в список доменов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но хотелось бы без изменения в файле hosts, сетка состоит из 100 машин.насчет dns тоже бы хотелось избежать и знаю, что такое возможно, потому что у нас на сервере сторонняя организация развернула свое ПО и оно доступно по всей сети.в hosts они не меняли ничего. к dns доступа у них нет...и своим секретом делиться они отказываются.

Comment: @Dmitrij никак тогда значит в днс добавил ваш админ по другому ну ни как